# Can I find specific characters in a string in Julia?

Tags: julia

So I started using Julia, and I wonder if you can find a character in a string. For example:

```
x = "hello."
```

looks for a `.` (if it is there)

removes the `.`

```
x = "hello"
```

---

my program based on the answers (works now!):

```
# hello.jl
# --- Greeting ---
println("Hello!")
println("How are you?")
# --- Input ---
x = readline()
# --- Put the characters in the ' ' for use later ---
removechar = ['.', '!', '*', '(', ')',' ']
# --- Fixing ---
fixedX = replace(lowercase(x), removechar => "")
# --- Print Answer ---
println("I'm ", fixedX, " too!")
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you wrote `remove = [".", "!"]` instead of `remove = ['.', '!']`

Comment: it was before where it was different @DNF

Comment: @DNF before, when i didn't even know about the replace command

Comment: @DNF I said i was new to Julia so how was i supposed to know

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now. I just told why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace several characters at once (I understand this is what you want) with the following `replace` syntax:

```
julia> replace("hello.", ['.', 'o','e'] => "")
"hll"
```

[image]

Comment: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching findnext(::Vector{String}, ::String, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  findnext(::AbstractChar, ::AbstractString, ::Integer) at strings/search.jl:321
  findnext(::Base.Fix2{var"#s79", var"#s78"} where {var"#s79"<:Union{typeof(==), typeof(isequal)}, var"#s78"<:AbstractChar}, ::String, ::Integer) at strings/search.jl:5
  findnext(::Function, ::AbstractString, ::Integer) at strings/search.jl:146
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] replace(str::String, pat_repl::Pair{Vector{String}, String}; count::Int64)

Comment: What Julia version do you use? And it works when searching for `Char`s what was your original question.

Comment: julia version 1.6.1

Comment: There is no magic here. Perhaps when you run from file you are using different Julia? Or you have double qouetes `"` instead of single quotes `'` ?

Comment: oh. I was using double quotes.

Comment: LoadError: syntax: invalid empty character literal
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ /Applications/Julia/hello.jl:4

Comment: You used `''` please read the answer you got carefully - it really matters where you use `"` and where you use `'`. The first one is for `String`s while the second is for `Char`s

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace` to replace characters in a string (even if those characters are not in the string):

```
julia> replace("hello.", "." => "")
"hello"

julia> replace("world", "." => "")
"world"
```

If you just want a boolean indicating whether a sub-string exists in a string, you can use `contains` or `occursin`:

```
julia> contains("the quick brown fox", "fox")
true

julia> occursin("fox", "the quick brown fox")
true
```

`contains` and `occursin` are basically the same, except the argument order is reversed. You can remember the argument order by reading the function name in between the two arguments, like this:

- `contains(x, y)`: "x contains y"
- `occursin(x, y)`: "x occurs in y"

Comment: can i check more than one time on just one?

Comment: like i don't have to do:

fixX1 = replace(lowercase(x), "." => "")

fixedX = replace(lowercase(fixX1), "!" => "")